# Looping ProgressBar Loader in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, progress-bar

I have some vba code that takes a good minute or so to run in excel and I was trying to add a progress bar or some type of waiting screen to better show to the user that the code is still running correctly. I realize that the ProgressBar can only show true progress in specific types of code, of which I do not believe mine would apply.

However, I was wondering if there was a way to have the ProgressBar just loop and once it is full it starts from the beginning again until my code has finished; in a similar fashion to a charging icon when a phone is plugged in. So upon activating my code, the UserForm1 would pop up and show a repeating ProgressBar and upon completion of my code the UserForm would Unload.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I use the following for a progress bar on a user form.  It consists of a label within a frame; at the beginning the label has width zero and then it widens to fill the frame at 100% completion. The label has no text, but it has a BackColor property set to serve as the bar. There's a second progressText label to the right of the frame. To call this function, use a loop such as `i = i + 1` with `pctCompl = 100 * i / iTotalNum`, and then include in the loop: `progress pctCompl, "listing files"`, and when finished make progress bar invisible with: `progress -1`.  You can always reset it to 0 using `pctCompl = 0` at any time.

```
Sub progress(pctCompl As Integer, Optional msg As String)
Dim increment As Double, i As Integer
If pctCompl < 0 Then
  If progressBar.Width < 0.9 * progressFrame.Width Then
    progressBar.Width = progressFrame.Width
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
  End If
  progressText.Visible = False
  progressFrame.Visible = False
  Exit Sub
 Else
  progressText.Visible = True
  progressFrame.Visible = True
End If
progressText.Caption = pctCompl & "% " & msg
progressBar.Width = progressFrame.Width * pctCompl / 100
DoEvents
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  progressFrame.Visible = False
  progressText.Visible = False
end Sub
```

Comment: instead of wait, you can doevents, or label.zorder 0, or put the label in a frame same size and frame.repaint.   Also use double instead of integer because vba will not be so confused about rounding numbers and max'es (if you dont get it try ?1000*1000 , or so, in immediate window, small number yet you get overflow error). To avoid slowing code, i often use if i mod 3=0then affProgress , for example, but you may change the value 3 to tweak it accordingly.